# How to serialize events in a database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, nosql

My problem is a bit complex, I'll try to simplify it with an example.

Let's say I want to implement a chat system backed with a SQL database. The
system consists of a single room on which anyone can post messages.

To use the chat, you need to install an app (think a mobile app). This app keeps
the history on the device and connects regularly to the server to get only the
new messages.

The problem I want to solve is how to get only these new messages **without losing
any of them**.

---

A naïve implementation would use a SQL table with two columns `(id
AUTO_INCREMENT, message)`. The client connects, gets the history the first time
and then only asks for messages whose id is greater than the last id they have.

It appears that in practice, this does not work, and you have a risk of missing
messages. I have made two programs that use PostgreSQL. One program only makes
inserts in the table, and the other program does `SELECT *` regularly and checks
that on each iteration, no new items appeared with an id smaller that the
biggest id of the previous iteration.

In other words, let's say you `SELECT *` on one iteration, you get ids 3, 5 and
9. Then on the next iteration you get 3, 5, 8 and 9. A new message appeared with
a smaller id than the biggest id of the previous iteration. This means that
if the client had asked for all ids bigger than 9, it would have missed 8.

I can provide the programs' sources if I was unclear.

Now, if I run one instance of the checker program and 5 instances of the
inserters, misses happen around 2 to 3 times per minute.

---

I need a database architecture to be able to implement a system where an app can
get only the new messages since the last connection. I took SQL as an example,
but I'm open to any other exotic NoSQL alternatives. If anyone knows how real
chat systems such as Signal, Whatsapp or others are implemented, I would also be
interested.

---

EDIT: The table for these examples is the following, which is a little different than the one described above:

```
create table test (id serial primary key, value int);
```

here's the code of the checker process:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unordered_set>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto const conninfo = "dbname = test password = postgres";

  PGconn* conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);
  if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
  {
    std::cerr << "error: " << PQerrorMessage(conn) << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  std::unordered_set<uint64_t> vals;
  uint64_t lastId = 0;

  while (true)
  {
    PGresult* res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
    {
      std::cerr << "error: " << PQerrorMessage(conn) << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++)
    {
      auto const id = std::atoll(PQgetvalue(res, i, 0));
      if (id <= lastId)
      {
        if (!vals.count(id))
        {
          std::cout << id << " was missed" << std::endl;
          vals.insert(id);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        vals.insert(id);
        lastId = id;
      }
    }

    PQclear(res);
  }

  PQfinish(conn);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's the code of the inserter process:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unordered_set>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto const conninfo = "dbname = test password = postgres";

  PGconn* conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);
  if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
  {
    std::cerr << "error: " << PQerrorMessage(conn) << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  while (true)
  {
    PGresult* res = PQexec(conn, "INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (1)");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
      std::cerr << "error: " << PQerrorMessage(conn) << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    PQclear(res);
  }

  PQfinish(conn);
  return 0;
}
```

Run one checker process and some 5 inserters (all compiled with at least -O2) and you will see occasional "xxx was missed" messages which prove that there are ids that are generated before the last id of the previous iteration.

One other way to prove that is the following. Start two psql shells, 1 and 2. I'll give the command to enter in order in each shell:

```
1> create table test (id serial primary key, value int);
1> begin;
1> insert into test (value) values (1);

2> insert into test (value) values (2);
2> select * from test;

-- you see the row (id:2, value:2) in the table

1> commit;

2> select * from test;

-- now you see (id:1, value:1) and (id:2, value:2)
-- an id smaller than 2 has just appeared
```

Comment: Your question is not following SO guidelines, as you're not raising a concrete problem with a code you're trying to solve, but a general design question. You should provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and point out what you're not understanding or what does not work in your example to follow SO's guidelines ☺

Answer (score 1):

well, based on your own explaination, your issue is very likely that your implementation does not respect your 'theoretical' approach. Because you don't provide an MCVE, I'll answer you based on that assumption.

If you really define `id` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then you'll never reach a situation where you'll have new messages with `id` inferior to the one the client has.

So, when a client writes a new message, it's without `id` and pushed in a queue to the server. On the client side you can show all messages from the queue as "tentative" using a colour coding (like a grey background).

When the server receives the messages, it does the `INSERT` and assign an id to the message.

Next time an update happens coming from the server, the client updates the list of messages since last highest `id` value. the user's own message will appear in order in the chat buffer. Then all messages that were in the queue can be discarded at the same time.

Then, you can guarantee the data being up to date at all time, because your invariant *"new message has always a higher id"* is always true.

That being said, it's a good idea to have a mix of ids and timestamp, and use the `id` field for the order you want to display your data, and the `timestamp` for querying all changes since last refresh. Then you can support message mutability (modify or delete).

---

Though, here's a free good advice: instead of reinventing the wheel, use an existing protocol that has been proven to work well over the years. You could use [XMPP+MUC](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html), [SILC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILC_(protocol)), [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRC) or [Axolotl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol) (there's a paper on [multiuser](http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2015/papers-archived/6949a232.pdf) chat with it).

Basically, chatting on internet is a problem solved many times, if you think you can make it better, don't reinvent the wheel, just add your contribution to existing stacks. You'll be interoperable with existing tools, libraries, framework with working implementations.

---

about your edit:

the issue you're having is two fold:

1. you're having concurrent insertion in the database directly ;
2. Postgresql breaks the atomicity rule of a transaction for `INSERT` statement, and specifically for an id's `AUTO_INCREMENT` rule, to help for efficient concurrent insertions.

So, your consideration that an `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed id will always be higher is a wrong hypothesis for your algorithm.

As a solution, you can:

- enforce [`gapless` increments](http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/130.php), at the cost of locking the database each time an insert within a transaction is happening,
- you can query your table based on timestamps (cf above),
- you can use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on your table to handle the auto increment a non auto-increment `id` value after insertion,
- you can use queues to communicate with the clients, and have a single worker handling insertion in the database,
- you can just not reinvent the wheel and use a proven known to work asynchronous protocol that support server-side logging for multi user chat, like [XMPP](https://xmpp.org/about/technology-overview.html).

Comment: Please see my edit above. As for the protocols you suggest, I don't actually want to implement a chat, and more importantly, in my use-case the connection can't stay open for long periods of time as it is the case with IRC or XMPP, it is more like Signal and Whatsapp.

Comment: XMPP does not require having connections opened for long periods of time, it's an asynchronous protocol!

Comment: Thanks for your edit. From what I read, gapless increments rely on the fact that a row is locked, similarly to your 4th point, only one insertion can be done at a time. While this works, I would have liked a solution that scales better, allowing me to spawn multiple servers connected to a single db. Using timestamps have the same problem than ids, an older timestamp can appear later (you can try with the transaction code I wrote in my edit). I didn't test it, but I highly doubt that a trigger will give me the atomicity I want here.

Comment: As for XMPP, I picked a server implementation (jabberd2) and looked at the code. They seem to keep a spool of pending messages that the user retrieves when they connect. The spool is flushed at that time. It seems to me that it is not atomic at all. It is probably ok for a chat protocol to drop one message every 10000, but I am not trying to write a chat protocol, this was just simpler a model of my problem. My system can't allow clients to lose messages.

Comment: well, then this is an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info). You're asking about a specific solution for a problem you have designing a solution for another problem. If what you need is a message queue, then use a message queue. Like rabbitmq, RestMQ (based on Redis), MQTT etc. They all offer different implementation of pubsub that should fit your use case.

Comment: You might want to check prosody (a lightweight XMPP implementation in Lua). AFAICT, even though atomicity might not be ensured, integrity of the communication is part of XMPP's design and I'm pretty sure there are mechanisms to never lose a message. But I'm not an XMPP expert.